Are questions about identifying encryption algorithms allowed?
I have an encryption algorithm I pulled out of a binary. I'd like to identify what the algorithm is, but I don't have the requisite crypto experience. The code is "high level" C# code, as opposed to something like assembly.
Is it okay to post the code here for assistance in identifying the algorithm? The help says

Do we accept questions asking for cryptanalysis of your cipher (hash function, ...) design?
No, we do not.



Can I get data analysed here? Can I challenge people to decode something?
No.

but I'm not sure either of those applies to my situation. At the very least, the help could be reworded slightly.

Google for the magic numbers in the code. Most crypto algos have those.

@CodesInChaos unfortunately, it seems like all the googleable magic numbers are in the initialization vector, not the algorithm itself...

[reverseengineering.se] may be of some help.

The same arguments apply as to deciphering data: a code dump would be unhelpful to anyone other than the original asker. So unless we want to change the rules, I think such a question would get closed as off topic.
However, like with deciphering questions, if you can reword it so that it is about general techniques and doesn't rely on (or even show?) the code you have, it could be a good question. You'd just have to be careful to scope it well so it is't too broad. And preferably show your research.
Ask yourself is it:

Useful to others.
Answerable in a few paragraphs.

If it fails either, it will probably be closed. If not, it may be OK.
